# No value exists in scope for the shorthand property. Either declare one or provide an initializer

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am new to TypeScript.

I am getting the error **No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'firstName'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.** when using Prisma with Next.js. I am trying to create a new user in my DB.

User model in `schema.prisma`

```
model User {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email         String   @unique
  firstName     String
  middleName    String?
  lastName      String
  dateOfBirth   DateTime
  mobileNumber  String   @unique
  idType        String
  idNumber      String   @unique
  idExpirtyDate DateTime
  idIssueState  DateTime
  streetAddress String
  suburb        String
  postCode      Int
  state         String
  bsb           Int      @unique
  accountNumber Int      @unique
  payIdType     String
  payId         String   @unique
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

`createUser()` function is as below.

```
export async function createUser(user: FormData) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      middleName,
      email,
      dateOfBirth,
      mobileNumber,
      idType,
      idNumber,
      idExpirtyDate,
      idIssueState,
      streetAdddress,
      suburb,
      postCode,
      state,
      bsb,
      accountNumber,
      payIdType,
      payId,
    },
  })
}
```

Below is the where I am getting the FormData. It is from a component.

```
  async function handleFormData(userData: FormData) {
    'use server'
    await createUser(userData)
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you expect to get the value for `firstName` from? The `FormData` object?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question. with the code for the FormData. It is coming directly from the form on Form submit. <form action={handleFormData}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{firstName}` shorthand only works if there's a variable with the name `firstName` in scope, as it is effectively the same as `{firstName: firstName}`.

You need to manually extract the parameters from the `FormData`.

```js
data : {
    firstName: user.get('firstName'),
    // etc.
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to just pass all the values from the `FormData`, you can convert it to an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
data: Object.fromEntries(user)
```

Comment: Thank you, understand. My inputs in the form are has the same name.<input name="firstName"... Does that make any difference?

Comment: @NadunPerera No, not really. The name of the input affects the name of the submitted parameter (so there would be a `firstName` parameter), but you still have to extract the value manually on the server. It's not automatically going to make a variable for it.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting the error Type 'FormDataEntryValue | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: @NadunPerera A simple way to get around that, if you're sure that you're getting strings, is to assert it: `user.get('firstName') as string`.